# (WPF) Ocultar Label y TextBox y mostrarlos segun las selecciones

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy iniciando en WPF y estoy haciendo un ejercicio simple para calcular áreas de diferentes figuras, el problema es que busco que cuando no tengo ninguna figura seleccionada no debería aparecer nada en la pantalla y cuando seleccione un radio button debería aparecer los textbox y labels que me indican que debo ingresar, he intentado con textbox.IsVisible = false pero me da error CS0200 que es solo lectura

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtResultado.IsReadOnly = true;

        lblLado.IsVisible = false;
        lblBase.IsVisible = false;
        lblAltura.IsVisible = false;
        lblRadio.IsVisible = false;
        lblApotema.IsVisible = false;
        lblResultado.IsVisible = false;

        txtLado.IsVisible = false;
        txtBase.IsVisible = false;
        txtAltura.IsVisible = false;
        txtRadio.IsVisible = false;
        txtApotema.IsVisible = false;
        txtResultado.IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblResultado.IsVisible = true;
        txtResultado.IsVisible = true;

        if (btnCuadrado.IsChecked==true)
        {
            lblLado.IsVisible = true;
            lblBase.IsVisible = false;
            lblAltura.IsVisible = false;
            lblRadio.IsVisible = false;
            lblApotema.IsVisible = false;

            txtLado.IsVisible = true;
            txtBase.IsVisible = false;
            txtAltura.IsVisible = false;
            txtRadio.IsVisible = false;
            txtApotema.IsVisible = false;

            txtResultado.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(txtLado) * 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En **WPF** las cosas son diferentes a **Windows Form**. Para lograr lo que quieres hacer debes poner lo siguiente:

```
textBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

En **Windows Form** está la **propiedad Visible**, la cual es de tipo **booleano**, la cual toma valores **true** o **false**. En **WPF** la propiedad **Visibility** es un **enum** y puede tener como posibles valores: **Visible**, **Hidden**, **Collapsed**.

Answer (score 0):

O podrias hacer uso de "Collapsed"

```
textBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```